# Error while fetching Token with certificate & RSA Key in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ssl, oauth, x509certificate, mtls

I am trying to fetch oauth token in NodeJS with key , certificate & client id.

Code for the same:

```
        var form =  {
            client_id : CLIENT_ID,
            grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        }
        var headers= {
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
        var option = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: CERTIFICATE_URL + "/oauth/token",
            headers,
            form,
            httpsAgent:new https.Agent({
                cert: CLIENT_CERTIFICATE.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
                key: CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
              })
          };
       
        request(option, function(error, response, body) {
                var token = null;
                console.log(error);
                console.log(JSON.parse(body).access_token)
                if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    token = JSON.parse(body).access_token;
                } else {
                    console.log(error)
                    error = error | new Error(body);
                }
                cb(error, token);
            });
```

But getting the following error :
Error: write EPROTO 140062523283264:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 40
2021-10-13T23:46:56.23+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:789:14) errno: 'EPROTO', code: 'EPROTO', syscall: 'write'

**The certificate & key is generated & fetched from the cloud environment itself.
This is a x509 MTLS based authentication.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to do it with axios library, request library seems to be deprecated.